# How to replace string in NSMutableAttributedString?

Tags: ios, iphone, string, swift

I have this :

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Welcome %@ to %@")
```

And I want to format this to add some other `NSMutableAttributedString` instead of `%@`

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `NSAttributeString` with another `NSAttributeString` by following way. here in this example, you need to fine location of `%@` symbol.

```
        let stringVariable = "Welcome @ location"

        var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:stringVariable)

        var attributedStringAnother = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"abc")


        attributedString.replaceCharactersInRange(NSRange(location: 8,length: 1), withAttributedString: attributedStringAnother)

        println(attributedString)
```

Here `location: 8` is a location `@` symbol.

Output is :

```
Welcome abc location{
}
```

Hope this help  you.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Welcome %@ to %@")

let result = attributedString.string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%@", withString:"TEST")

var newAtrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: result)
```

Comment: I want to replace this string with other attributed string. Not with NSString

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you can do it this way:

`var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Welcome \(anotherAttributedString1) to \(anotherAttributedString2)")`